# Holomorphic stability of inverse limit of pre-$C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let *A* be a C*-algebra and let *A<sub>t</sub>* be a set of dense *-subalgebras of *A*, stable under holomorphic functional calculus on *A*, which are also Banach algebras complete with respect to the norms ||$\cdot$||<sub>t</sub>. Suppose also that the algebra *A*<sub>sup</sub> consisting of the elements *a* in *A* for which ||*a*||<sub>sup</sub>:=sup<sub>t</sub> ||*a*||<sub>t</sub>  < $\infty$ is dense in *A*.

Will the algebra *A*<sub>sup</sub> be also stable under the holomorphic functional calculus, or some additional considerations are needed?

Comment: You probably already know this, but I think this is if and only if $A_{\sup}$ has spectral permanence-- i.e. for each $a\in A_{\sup}$, the spectrum of $a$ in either $A$ or $A_{\sup}$ is the same.  But that doesn't (to me) seem easy to check.

Comment: Yep, that's the point. I've tried several techniques, in particular considering the MacLaurin series of the function in the point $\zeta \in \mathrm{C}$\Sp(a), and then making an estimation, but apparently this doesn't work. In fact I'm free to use the notion of holomorphic stability by Blackadar and Cuntz since I have the families of $A_\sup$ norms. But I just wanted to know, whether this information is redundant. 